# After upgrade magento 2.3.6 to 2.4.2 issue

Tags: error, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.2

**After upgrade magento 2.3.6 to 2.4.2 i getting this error when follow setup upgrade :-**

[image]

Comment: add this to your command --backend-frontname="admin"

Comment: hope this will work

Comment: Like this sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade --backend-frontname="admin"  ???

Comment: Disable third-party modules and then run upgrade command. Probably some code in the extension where area code is not set.

Comment: Oky Let me check.. Thank you. :)

Comment: while installing add this to your installation command

Comment: I can not understand can you please explain in detail??